# Comparing java.sql.Timestamp and LocalDate using slick?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have a slick column that is a Rep[Option[Timestamp]]. I'd like to compare it to a user supplied java.util.LocalDate via the filter method. I'm only interested in comparing the date (ddMMyyyy), not the time:

```
val userSuppliedLocalDate: LocalDate = ...
usersTable.filter(_.modifiedDate === userSuppliedLocalDate).result // Doesn't compile
```

I thought about converting the Rep[Timestamp] (_.modifiedDate) to a LocalDate, but unsure if this is possible (unwrapping a Rep type?)

Or, converting the userSuppliedLocalDate to a java.sql.Timestamp and doing a comparison ignoring the time portions -  is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Not recommended way

```
 Warning: Take care of time zone information
```

You can convert `LocalDate` into timestamp and compare the timestamp.

```
val timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(localDate.atStartOfDay)
```

Your method becomes

```
val userSuppliedLocalDate: LocalDate = ...
val userSuppliedTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(localDate.atStartOfDay)
usersTable.filter(_.modifiedDate === userSuppliedTimestamp).result
```

But, this is not the recommended way.

If you want to compare timestamp of particular day. One Hack would be

```
val start = Timestamp.valueOf(localDate.atStartOfDay())
val end = Timestamp.valueOf(start.plusDays(1))

usersTable.filter(row => row.modifiedDate >= start && row.modifiedDate < end).result
```

#### Recommended way is to use `LocalDate` itself as slick table column.

How is this possible?

```
This possible with slick column mapper.
```

Have below implicit in the scope.

```
implicit val mapper = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDate, Timestamp](
 _.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate(),
 Timestamp.valueOf)
```

Now you can have a `LocalDate` column directly

```
def birthday = column[LocalDate]("birthday")
```

Now you can directly compare

```
def birthdaysBefore(localDate: LocalDate) = 
  query.filter(_.birthday < localDate).result
```

You can use other comparison operators as well.

Comment: For the 'Not recommended way', I want to ignore the times, is this possible? (I only want to compare the dates)

Comment: Thanks, what about _.modifiedDate - do we need to change this to atStartOfDay as well (otherwise the times might be different?). Although not sure I can modify it via the filter function

Comment: @Rory Added more to the answer. please check